# js-hotkeys - how to bind to the ? question mark

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, binding, hotkeys, jquery-hotkeys

I've been using [js-hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) for a while, love it.

I'd now like to bind to the <kbd>?</kbd> key, but that doesn't appear to be supported. Anyone know why and how to bind to the <kbd>?</kbd> question mark?

```
$(document).bind('keydown', '?',function (evt) {
    alert('go');
});
```

The above code does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 191)
       alert("go");
});
```

Comment: This only works on QWERTY keyboards because "?" is on the "/" key. When you hit "?", it triggers key code 191, which is "/".

Answer (score 3):

I believe the event has a flag for whether the shift key was pressed, so you probably want to do something like this (i've never used js-hotkeys, so I may be completely wrong):

```
$(document).bind('keydown', '/', function (evt)
{
  if (evt.shiftKey) //or whatever the flag for the shift key may be
  {
    alert('go');
  }
});
```

Comment: of course, this also assumes that the `?` is the alternative on the `/` key. If you're using semantic shortcuts, you're probably better off listening for the correct `keyCode`

Comment: i don't get it. You are saying I should use the shift key + ?

Comment: I'm saying you should bind it to the `shift key` plus the `/` key as that's what creates a `?` on a standard `qwerty` keyboard.

Comment: what if the user isn't using a standard qwerty keyboard?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see that was your own comment already pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that the following will trigger even inside of an input box:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 191)
       alert("go");
});
```

Solution:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 191 && !$(e.target).is("input")) 
        alert("go");
});
```

Keep in mind that the same thing will happen for `texarea`.

Answer (score 0):

Using js-hotkeys, you would bind the Question Mark using the string:

```
shift+/
```